# RxJava window and switchMap never emit due to large sample

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, android-sensors

Running into a curious problem and want to find out if there is a way around it.

A little background first. I'm using ReactiveSensors in an Android app to aggregate sensor data. I am also reading GPS location. Because location updates are about 1 second apart, I use them as trigger points to drive sensor aggregation.

As such, I have this rough code composition:

```
Observable<LocationStruct> locationObservable = LocationService.getLocationObservable(context);

Observable<List<MinMaxAvg>> accelerometerObservable = mRxSensors.observeSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
            .onBackpressureDrop()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .filter(ReactiveSensorFilter.filterSensorChanged())
            .compose(extractSensorEventValues()) // simply maps rxsensor to sensor.values
            .window(locationObservable) // the important part, which opens window
            .map(Observable::share) // window cannot have multiple subscribers so I share it... somewhere further in code I have them
            .compose(computeMinMaxAvg(Observable.range(0, 3)))
            .filter(list -> list.size() > 0) // want to make sure only windows with data propagate to the subscriber
            .startWith(new ArrayList<MinMaxAvg>()) // in case the sensor doesn't have an immediate value
```

So as you can see, between location updates, other sensor (accelerometer and others, following similar patterns) updates are collected into windows and are processed. The main processing logic happens in `computeMinMaxAvg`:

```
private Observable.Transformer<Observable<float[]>, List<MinMaxAvg>> computeMinMaxAvg(Observable<Integer> indices) {
    return observable -> observable
            .switchMap(valuesObservable -> indices // switchMap rebinds to the observable returned, allowing to GC old observable
                    .flatMap(index -> { // for each index provided, pick the value from the array at index
                        Observable<Float> value = valuesObservable
                                .map(values -> values[index]).share();

                        // compute min, max, avg and zip it into the structure
                        return Observable.zip(
                                MathObservable.min(value),
                                MathObservable.max(value),
                                MathObservable.averageFloat(value),
                                MinMaxAvg::new
                        ).onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty());
                    })
                    .toList()
            );
}
```

The end result for accelerometer will be multidimensional array. The inner array will have min, max, avg while outer will have x, y, z.

A little explanation regarding the `computeMinMaxAvg` function. Sensor collection is a long running operation. As such, I had to use `switchMap` so that windows along with all the generated data, are unsubscribed when a new window arrives. Alternatively, memory leak occurs because allocated values are never GC.

However, I run into a weird case with accelerometer in particular (other sensors are doing better)... the sensor produces around 50 updates within 1 second (location updates). It seems that before `computeMinMaxAvg` is done processing all the data (50 sensor readings x 3 sensor points [x, y, z]), a new window comes along. This new windows forces `switchMap` to unsubscribe from the previous calculation. As the result, the expected list is never emitted because observable is unsubscribed from before it finishes generating the data.

My question is whether anyone can help in figuring out a way to make the computation faster so that I can get the result. May a use of different operators? I was looking into `buffer` but I think it will be the same deal as with `window`... maybe except i can manually calculate min, max, avg (which may be faster?).

Anyway, any help is greatly appreciated!!